# Not Displaying Stripe Customer Info in my Supabase Table

Tags: stripe-payments, supabase, supabase-database

I am using NextJs to create a stripe customer subscription and I have set up a webhook to interract with my stripe account, but I am not seeing the users data in my supabase table.

First here is the code:

```js
import getRawBody from "raw-body";
import { stripe } from "src/pricing/utils/stripe";
import { supabase } from "supabase";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];
  const signingSecret = process.env.STRIPE_SIGNING_SECRET;

  let event;
  try {
    const rawBody = await getRawBody(req, { limit: "2mb" });
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(rawBody, signature, signingSecret);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Webhook signature verification failed");
    return res.status(400).end();
  }

  try {
    switch (event.type) {
      case "customer.subscription.updated":
        await updateSubscription(event);
        break;
      case "customer.subscription.deleted":
        await deleteSubsctiption(event);
        break;
    }
    res.send({ success: true });
    console.log(event);
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.send({ status: false });
    return;
  }
}

async function updateSubscription(event) {
  const subscription = event.data.object;
  const stripe_customer_id = subscription.customer;
  const subscription_status = subscription.status;
  const price = subscription.items.data[0].price.id;
  const { data: profile } = await supabase
    .from("profile")
    .select("*")
    .eq("stripe_customer_id", stripe_customer_id)
    .single();

  if (profile) {
    const updatedSubscription = {
      subscription_status,
      price,
    };
    await supabase
      .from("profile")
      .update(updatedSubscription)
      .eq("stripe_customer_id", stripe_customer_id);
  } else {
    const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(stripe_customer_id);
    const name = customer.name;
    const email = customer.email;
    const newProfile = {
      name,
      email,
      stripe_customer_id,
      subscription_status,
      price,
    };
    await supabase.auth.admin.createUser({
      email,
      email_confirm: true,
      user_metadata: newProfile,
    });
  }

  return;
}
```

Before seting up my function this is displaying on my supabase authentication tab.
[Before setting Up Supabase Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WZiy.png)

But after setting up a function I cant see anything, please help me out on how i can set up my supabase function so that the info can be displayed on my supabase table

I made a query to my database[database query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX3Ip.png)

And I could find the data in the Supabase Database.

But, I can't use the data, or move it to a table

Comment: The screenshot you have attached are the auth page of the Supabase dashboard, which is not where you have stored your Stripe data. You have to go to your table editor within your Supabase dashboard and view the `profiles` table to view all the stripe data changes.